# Xamarin Forms Shell, is it possible to preload pages before the user actually navigates to the page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a few issues with `Xamarin.Communitytoolkit` which doesn't load the video and then shows the page it waits for the page to appear to then actually load the video giving a very bad user experience with flicker loading and occasionally stutters or constant pause play effect.

I want to be able to load a page onto a stack way before the user actually clicks the next button which navigates to that page creating a new instance.

I saw this post on [How to pre-load pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69350931/pre-load-pages-on-xamarin-forms) on SO but the problem is that this doesn't use shell so they don't have to deal with `Routing`. Also navigation is much different in `Shell` doing `Shell.Current.GoToAsync(URI type navigation string?queries)`

Is this possible to do with `Shell`? And if so how?

**Update**: After doing more research is that I need to insert a new page to the navigation stack before the user clicks next to then navigate to that page. This way the page will have everything ready for the user without loading anything again. This is actually happening while navigating backwards on the stack and there is nothing to do with the visual glitches which I see.

Many Thanks in advance.

```
public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(ListenAndViewPage), typeof(ListenAndViewPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(SpellPage), typeof(SpellPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(CopyWhatIDoPage), typeof(CopyWhatIDoPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(QuizPage), typeof(QuizPage));
}
```

**Update-2**:
I have a `JSON` file with `Levels` for my games and each level contains a `Video` path.

I have a Json reader which reads the file and then `deserialize` into my `Level` obj.

I then made a `LevelReader` which has methods to extract level data depending on `CurrentLevel` + other params if needed.

I load the `MediaElement` source with data binding from my ViewModel for the page.

The videos are part of `iOS` & `Android` projects as `Android Resource or Bundle Resource`.

Comment: I don't know if preloading the pages is the way to go, it might be but it depends on where the bottleneck actually is. Where, when and how do you load the videos?

Comment: @ewerspej I've updated as requested for more information. I've tried everything with loading videos even pre-loading into memory before hand. It is the `MediaElement` that causes the issues and the only way I see the fix is to insert a new page before the user clicks e.g. on start of the app and the once the user clicks next as that happens insert the next page along and always keep **ONLY** one instance of that page not many reducing the use or actual memory of the device. Once the users clicks back keep the same instance unit they click back twice. Does that make sense, kinda hard to explain

Comment: FWIW: When testing any performance issue, be sure to test **on an actual device, without debugger attached**. This can be a Debug build; but "Start without Debugging" (or after launching to device, kill app, start again from icon on device's home page). Have you tested this way?

Comment: Is the video a local file, or a URL to web? What is its resolution? bit datarate? If you test with a small local video, does it work correctly?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve the video is a local file yes, it is not URL. Resolution is portrait 1080p, fps 60, tested it with local video and also tested with a small video but each video is no more than 3 seconds long anyways. Also tested without the debugger same issue. This doesn't happen on iPhone only on Android.

Comment: Maybe this could be an alternative to enhance the user experience [Show a activity indicator while View content is loading in Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404158/show-a-activity-indicator-while-view-content-is-loading-in-xamarin-forms)